# Test vector for PKSC1V2.2 RSASSA-PSS signature scheme

Tags: c, testing, cryptography, rsa, pkcs#1

I'm working on PKSC1V2.2 RSASSA-PSS Signature Scheme. I got some standard test vector for the final results testing, but my results are not matching. 
To check where my code is going wrong, I need some test vector with intermediate result.

and I'm using RSA 2048 and SHA 256.

please help ... if anyone has it or if you know where can I get it? also any other method to test it.

Regards

Comment: You're using SHA-256 just as hash or as hash of MGF1 or both? Do you have any specific hash values that fail? What exactly goes wrong? Note that PSS is *non-deterministic* (i.e. randomized) so getting identical results requires a preset PRNG.

Comment: @Maarten, I'm using SHA-256 for both Hash as well as MGF1's hash. and in the test vector which I got the Seed value was there, so I'm hard coding the Seed for testing purpose and not using PRNG. still I didn't got the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to take any other implementation and use step through or trace logging (printing to console) the intermediate values. You could also take the output of a known good implementation and reverse the modular exponentiation (raw encrypt with the public key) to get to the padding.

The main thing is indeed the padding. For instance Bouncy Castle has a `org.bouncycastle.crypto.test.MGF1GeneratorTest` class to test MGF1. That should be easy enough to step through.